# Mongoose not saving data to mLab

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, passport-local

After many failed attempts at correcting my logic I am resorting to asking for help.

I am using Node, Express, Passport, Mongoose, MongoDB to create an application. So far a user can sign up and log in. When the user signs up they are defined by this Schema:

```
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({

  local : {
    username : String,
    password : String,
  },
  jobs : [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed }]

});
```

Saving the user is done by this:

```
  var newUser = new User();

          // set the user's local credentials
          newUser.local.username = username;
          newUser.local.password = newUser.generateHash(password);
          newUser.jobs = [];
          // save the user
          newUser.save(function(err) {
            if (err) {
              console.log(err);
              throw err;
            }
        console.log('user saved: ', newUser);
        return done(null, newUser);
      });
```

Which results in this MongoDB doc:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "596a436a2981ab1729a4f08b"
    },
    "local": {
        "password": "$2a$08$TV2rADNbm302cREGRzfRFOtZF4mA8kYCeBjcmalPCk./flUO3wM.6",
        "username": "kev"
    },
    "__v": 0
}
```

Notice the missing jobs entry. I did not think that would be a problem, although, now when I try updating the doc by adding a job using:

```
User.findOne(
      { 'local.username': req.user.username },
      // { $push: { 'jobs':{'website': req.body.joblink } } },
      // { returnNewDocument: true },
      function(err, user) {

        // if there are any errors, return the error
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
          return done(err);
        } else {
          user.jobs = [];
          user.jobs.push( {'website': req.body.joblink} );
          console.log(user.jobs);
          user.save(function(err) {
            if (err) {
              console.log(err);
              throw err;
            }
            console.log('user updated: ', user);
            res.redirect('/profile');
          });
        }
    });
```

The Mongo doc is unchanged while the

> console.log('user updated: ', user);

displays the correct document.

Comment: You say *"The Mongo doc is unchanged"* but where are you actually looking at the document? This code does not attempt to read the modified document. If you are looking at the data "manually" then make sure that: 1. You are in fact looking at the same document you think you are modifying ( note there is nothing stopping `.findOne()` selecting only "one" of many possible documents ). 2. That you are actually looking at the correct collection, since mongoose models by default use the "plural" collection name, in this case `"users"` given `'User'` as a model name.

Comment: I am looking at the document in mLab which I am using for my database storage. I am definitely looking at the same document I am modifying, as there should not be duplicate users within the users collection. If I have created the collection correctly I created a collection called users which will store documents called User, where the schema model is displayed above.

Answer (score 0):

```
You should use findOneAndUpdate() method of mongodb

    https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/
    Like that
    var json = {'website': req.body.joblink};

    User.findOneAndUpdate(
       { 'local.username': req.user.username },
        { $push: { jobs: json });
```

You have to update your schema:-

```
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({

      local : {
        username : String,
        password : String,
      },
      jobs : {

        type: Array,
        default: []
       }

    });
```

After updating schema , When you first time save document and if you are not passing jobs in json, It will automatically create a default array.

After that you can use $push to update jobs

Comment: Whilst it would indeed be "better" to use `.findOneAndUpdate()` or even just plain `.update()` in order to make a modification, this is not the actual cause of the problem posted in the question. Using `.save()` is not the "best" practice, but it certainly does work. Also please don't write in answers using examples that clearly do not apply to the question asked. They are not asking to set `"name"` or `"assignment"` or increment a `"points"` field. Such responses "look like" ( and quite often are ) simple rips from other answers. Especially when the response does not explain the actions.

Comment: To be more blunt. You are [copying this "answer" from this source](https://github.com/mongodb/docs/blob/master/source/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate.txt#L209), And the lack of explanation of operators and incorrect teminology ( it's not JSON ) points to that you simply demonstrated you can use a search engine, more than an understanding of the correct operation or answer to the question.

Comment: I attempted using `.findOneAndUpdate()` initially but to no avail did I solve the problem I am facing. I used `$push` to attempt updating the array but there is no array in the document to begin with when a new user signs up. @NeilLunn @ashish-maurya

Comment: @klewis I have updated my answer , I hope this will help you.

Comment: @ashish-maurya Thanks for the update, I attempted modifying the schema and using `findOneAndUpdate()` but the database still saves a doc without jobs. Both when creating a new user and attempting to update.

Comment: @ashishmaurya I'm using version 4.11.3 which I believe is the latest version